How to code survey question results with randomized order choices?
I'm cleaning data from a qualtrics survey that includes a few questions where the answer choices were randomized (e.g. you rate five tv shows, and the show order is randomized for each respondent). The answers show up as separate columns for each: e.g. tv_show_1, tv_show_2 with the rows being individual respondents' ratings (excellent, good, bad etc.), and then there is a column that tells me the display order for each individual survey respondent, with tv shows separated using vertical bars like this|.
I've never worked with anything like this and am a bit stumped. I'd love some help figuring out how to write R code or a function that can take the display order column and use it to categorize the answers given in the prior five columns (or whatever else you can think of that would be better than that). Thank you!
I haven't tried anything yet! Just glancing at the data
Here is an example of what the data look like (this is made up for the example!):
respondents <- c("Respondent 1", "Respondent 2", "Respondent 3")
tv_show_1 <- c("excellent", "good", "bad")
tv_show_2 <- c("good", "bad", "neutral")
tv_show_3 <- c("neutral", "good", "neutral")
tv_show_DO <- c("Friends|Seinfeld|Full House", "Seinfeld|Friends|Full House", "Seinfeld|Full House|Friends")


df <- data.frame(respondents, tv_show_1, tv_show_2, tv_show_3, tv_show_DO)
print(df)


thank you for adding that. I would also look into the survey itself, respondents may have been shown the questions in different orders but behind the scenes the questions may be stored in the same column. For example questions about Friends could have been shown in any position but is always assigned as question 1 in the backend

You have a combination of data encoded by column name (e.g. tv_show_1) and data encoded by position (e.g. a|b|c). There are many ways to approach this, but for further analysis I'd suggest putting the data into tidy format where the position encoding is made explicit in its own column. We can do this separately for the two types of data and then combine them.
Note that this approach would work for any number of items, as the only columns specified are the respondents and tv_show_DO ones.
First, I collect the rating columns and pivot them longer.
library(tidyverse)
df_ratings <- df |>
  select(-tv_show_DO) |>
  pivot_longer(-respondents)

We can do something similar for the delimited data, assigning each row a name that matches the pattern for the other data.
df_shows <- df |>
  select(respondents, tv_show_DO) |>
  separate_longer_delim(tv_show_DO, delim = "|") |>
  mutate(name = paste0("tv_show_", row_number()), .by = respondents)

And finally combine:
df_shows |>
  left_join(df_ratings)

This gives us a nice "long format" table combining all the data, in a way that will make further analysis simpler. For example, here you can directly test how well randomized the shows are by comparing the show to its position, or test if the ratings vary depending on sequencing, etc.
   respondents tv_show_DO      name     value
1 Respondent 1    Friends tv_show_1 excellent
2 Respondent 1   Seinfeld tv_show_2      good
3 Respondent 1 Full House tv_show_3   neutral
4 Respondent 2   Seinfeld tv_show_1      good
5 Respondent 2    Friends tv_show_2       bad
6 Respondent 2 Full House tv_show_3      good
7 Respondent 3   Seinfeld tv_show_1       bad
8 Respondent 3 Full House tv_show_2   neutral
9 Respondent 3    Friends tv_show_3   neutral


Using by, you could split the respondents, strsplit the show variable at the "|" and along the derived alphabetical order sort the unlisted ratings. Give the sorted names of the TV shows.
> res <- by(df, df$respondents, \(x) {
+   shw <- el(strsplit(x$tv_show_DO, '\\|'))
+   tv <- unlist(x[grep('^tv_show_[1-3]', names(x))])[order(shw)] |> 
+     setNames(sort(shw)) |> t() |> as.data.frame()
+   cbind(respondents=x[, 1], tv)
+ }) |> do.call(what='rbind')
> res
              respondents   Friends Full House Seinfeld
Respondent 1 Respondent 1 excellent    neutral     good
Respondent 2 Respondent 2       bad       good     good
Respondent 3 Respondent 3   neutral    neutral      bad

Often, subsequently long format is desired which you can get like so:
> res |> 
+   reshape2::melt(id='respondents')
   respondents   variable     value
1 Respondent 1    Friends excellent
2 Respondent 2    Friends       bad
3 Respondent 3    Friends   neutral
4 Respondent 1 Full House   neutral
5 Respondent 2 Full House      good
6 Respondent 3 Full House   neutral
7 Respondent 1   Seinfeld      good
8 Respondent 2   Seinfeld      good
9 Respondent 3   Seinfeld       bad

Note: Please check beforehand if answers are really also stored randomly (@Mike's comment) beforehand to not create a mess.

Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(respondents = c("Respondent 1", "Respondent 2", 
"Respondent 3"), tv_show_1 = c("excellent", "good", "bad"), tv_show_2 = c("good", 
"bad", "neutral"), tv_show_3 = c("neutral", "good", "neutral"
), tv_show_DO = c("Friends|Seinfeld|Full House", "Seinfeld|Friends|Full House", 
"Seinfeld|Full House|Friends")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))


You can extract the show names into a named vector where the values come from tv_show_DO and the names come from tv_show_*. Then from there you can decide how to format your output.
Note: this assumes tv_show_* is in the same order (left to right) as the | separated show names in tv_show_DO.
Long Format
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(show = list(str_split(tv_show_DO, fixed("|"))[[1]] |>
                       setNames(c_across(matches("tv_show_\\d"))))) |>
  unnest_longer(show, indices_to = "rating", keep_empty = TRUE)
# # A tibble: 9 × 7
#   respondents  tv_show_1 tv_show_2 tv_show_3 tv_show_DO             show  rating
#   <chr>        <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>                  <chr> <chr> 
# 1 Respondent 1 excellent good      neutral   Friends|Seinfeld|Full… Frie… excel…
# 2 Respondent 1 excellent good      neutral   Friends|Seinfeld|Full… Sein… good  
# 3 Respondent 1 excellent good      neutral   Friends|Seinfeld|Full… Full… neutr…
# 4 Respondent 2 good      bad       good      Seinfeld|Friends|Full… Sein… good  
# 5 Respondent 2 good      bad       good      Seinfeld|Friends|Full… Frie… bad   
# 6 Respondent 2 good      bad       good      Seinfeld|Friends|Full… Full… good  
# 7 Respondent 3 bad       neutral   neutral   Seinfeld|Full House|F… Sein… bad   
# 8 Respondent 3 bad       neutral   neutral   Seinfeld|Full House|F… Full… neutr…
# 9 Respondent 3 bad       neutral   neutral   Seinfeld|Full House|F… Frie… neutr…

Wide Format
Simply use unnest_wider() instead:
df |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(show = list(str_split(tv_show_DO, fixed("|"))[[1]] |>
                       setNames(c_across(matches("tv_show_\\d"))))) |>
  unnest_wider(show)
# # A tibble: 3 × 9
#   respondents  tv_show_1 tv_show_2 tv_show_3 tv_show_DO  excellent good  neutral
#   <chr>        <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>       <chr>     <chr> <chr>  
# 1 Respondent 1 excellent good      neutral   Friends|Se… Friends   Sein… Full H…
# 2 Respondent 2 good      bad       good      Seinfeld|F… <NA>      Sein… <NA>   
# 3 Respondent 3 bad       neutral   neutral   Seinfeld|F… <NA>      <NA>  Full H…
# # ℹ 1 more variable: bad <chr>

